# How to default construct value_type of iterator as default argument in the function?

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, c++14, default-constructor

Here is the abomination:

```
template <typename BidirIt, typename OutputIt, typename T,
          typename BinaryDoOp, typename BinaryUndoOp>
void sliding_window(BidirIt first, BidirIt last, OutputIt d_first,
                    typename std::iterator_traits<BidirIt>::difference_type length,
                    T init = typename std::iterator_traits<BidirIt>::value_type(),
                    BinaryDoOp op = std::plus<>{},
                    BinaryUndoOp undo = std::minus<>{})
```

So I want `T` to be `std::iterator_traits<BidirIt>::value_type` by default and default construct an object of that type giving it a name `init`.

After solving a problem of fitting some of the variable types in one line, I found that compiler is not able to deduce `T`, here is what it exactly says:

> error: no matching function for call to 'sliding_window'
>       sliding_window(v.begin(), v.end(), output.begin(), window_length/*, 0, std::plus<>(), std::minus<>()*/);
>
> note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'
>   void sliding_window(BidirIt first, BidirIt last, OutputIt d_first,

My compiler is clang++-3.9.

Call site code:

```
std::vector<int> v(window_length + window_count - 1);
std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);

std::vector<int> output(window_count);
std::vector<int> correct_result{3, 6, 9, 12};

sliding_window(v.begin(), v.end(), output.begin(), window_length/*, 0, std::plus<>(), std::minus<>()*/);
```

When the commented part is uncommented code works correctly.

From what I know about templates, it should be able to deduce that type since it is practically a default constructor call there, which should yield `std::iterator_traits<BidirIt>::value_type`. Do I have any misunderstanding of how type of default arguments work when function is templated on a type?

**Question:** how to fix it? It would be great to add some explanations to it too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Template types cannot be deduced from defaulted templated arguments: [C++14 lambda's default argument type deduction depending on preceding arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42240849/c14-lambdas-default-argument-type-deduction-depending-on-preceding-arguments/42241026#42241026). As far as how to fix it, you would need to default the types:

```
template <typename BidirIt, typename OutputIt,
    typename T = typename std::iterator_traits<BiDirIt>::value_type,
    typename BinaryDoOp = std::plus<>,
    typename BinaryUndoOp = std::minus<>>
void sliding_window(BidirIt first, BidirIt last, OutputIt d_first,
                typename std::iterator_traits<BidirIt>::difference_type length,
                T init = T{},
                BinaryDoOp op = BinaryDoOp{},
                BinaryUndoOp undo = BinaryUndoOp{})
```

Another approach would also be to have overloaded functions, where the ones with fewer template parameters/arguments call the ones with more and handle the defaulting at the call site. This is the approach used by `std::accumulate`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate. Then you'd have multiple functions so there's some repetition there, but each one is quite a bit more readable.

Comment: Thanks for additional information. Jarod's version compiles correctly and I believe it is standard conformant, so may be leaving out types on the rhs of = is a good idea?

Comment: The different overloads can delegate to each other, so repetition shouldn't be a problem.  Unless you are talking about the interface itself ...

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
template <typename BidirIt,
          typename OutputIt,
          typename T = typename std::iterator_traits<BidirIt>::value_type,
          typename BinaryDoOp = std::plus<>,
          typename BinaryUndoOp = std::minus<>>
void sliding_window(BidirIt first,
                    BidirIt last,
                    OutputIt d_first,
                    typename std::iterator_traits<BidirIt>::difference_type length,
                    T init = {},
                    BinaryDoOp op = {},
                    BinaryUndoOp undo = {})
```

The template type are not deduced from default value.
So you have to set default types manually.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Explanations would be great for future readers, but from the looks of it they seem obvious